# unable to update windows phone ui after webservice request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I could successfully make a request and get response from webservice in windows phone, but I couldn't update the UI using the result I got from response, it is showing invalid cross thread exception.

Here is my code:

```
public void UpdateUI()
{
    check = dat.Count;
    for (int ci = 0; ci < check; ci++)
    {
        Datum dt = new Datum();
        dt = dat[ci];
        Title1 = dt.title;
        Price = dt.price;
        Id = dt.id;
        Logo = dt.logo;
        Featured = dt.featured;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UpdateUI");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Title1.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Price.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Id.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Logo.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Featured.ToString());


        Grid grd = new Grid();
        grd.Name = "grd" + ci;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(grd.Name);
        grd.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
        grd.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);

        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = 150;
        img.Height = 120;
        img.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.searchi.in/classifieds/dashboard/classifieds_images/big/"+Logo, UriKind.Absolute);

        ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        img.Source = imgSource;

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.MaxWidth=125;
        tb.Height = 100;
        tb.Text = Title1;
        tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        tb.FontSize = 22;
        tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;



        TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
        tb1.Width = 300;
        tb1.Height = 100;
        tb1.Text = " ₹ "+Price;

        tb1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        tb1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        tb1.FontSize = 22;

        tb1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

        grd.Children.Add(img);
        grd.Children.Add(tb);
        grd.Children.Add(tb1);
        grid.Children.Add(grd);

    }

}
```

and code for request:

```
void web()
{
    // Create the web request object
    var url = "http://searchi.in/appservice/classifides.php";
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Start the request

    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);
    //asynchronousResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
   // webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);

}

void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
    postStream.Close();
    // datacheck = 1;
    cheker = true;
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);

    // asynchronous = asynchronousResult;
    //asynchronousResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("2");
}

void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("3");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        Response = readStream.ReadToEnd().ToString();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetResponseCallback");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Response);
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        RootObject ro = (RootObject)serializer2.ReadObject(receiveStream);

        Success = ro.success;
        Sort = ro.sort;
        dat = ro.data;

        readStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        //cheker = true;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    UpdateUI();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap call to `UpdateUI()` function with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. That will invoke the function from UI thread to prevent invalid cross thread exception :

```
......
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        UpdateUI();
    });
......
```